# How to hide DataTable's column header in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, datatable

How to hide the columns header of DataTable in Flutter?
[DataTable in Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html)

```
DataTable(
  headingRowHeight: 0,
  columns: <DataColumn>[
  DataColumn(label: Text("Name")),
  DataColumn(label: Text("Hour")),
  DataColumn(label: Text("Tag")),
  DataColumn(label: Text("Date")),
  DataColumn(label: Text("Action")),

], rows: lstCourse.map((e) => DataRow(
  cells: <DataCell>[
    DataCell(Text(e.Name)),
    DataCell(Text(e.Hour_Text)),
    DataCell(Text(e.Tag)),
    DataCell(Text(e.StartDate_Text)),
    DataCell(RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text("Đăng ký"),)),
  ]
)).toList()
);
```

I have try to find some option in DataTable class but seem not exist

Comment: Set `headingRowHeight` = 0.0 ?

Comment: @Kahou Set headingRowHeight not work

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the relevant html and code (as text, not a link)? There may be various possible solutions, but it depends on how your table is defined.

Comment: @andrewjames already updated

Comment: Can you show the html definition for the table? Or show how the HTML is generated?

Comment: What is "not work" mean?

Comment: @Kahou The DataTable still display the columns header

Comment: how to specify hide header ? for example column 'ID" ? `headingRowHeight: 0,` is just hide all .

Answer (score 17):

headingRowHeight to 0, empty container to DataColumn label

```
DataTable(
         headingRowHeight: 0,
         columns: [
           DataColumn(label: Container()),
           DataColumn(label: Container()),
           DataColumn(label: Container()),
           DataColumn(label: Container()),
           DataColumn(label: Container()),
         ],
         rows: ..
    ),
```

Comment: The first divider remains there, so I also used `dividerThickness: double.minPositive` to get rid of all the dividers. I don't have any idea how to get rid of only the very first divider though.

Answer (score 7):

Set headingRowHeight to 0 and all label text to be empty string `DataColumn(label: Text(""))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable(
                headingRowHeight: 0,
                  columns: const [
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text(''),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text('')),
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text('')),
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text('')),
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text('')),
              ],
```

Combine `headingRowHeight:0` and `Text("")`

Answer (score -1):

if (your condition)
DataColumn(
label: Text('your column name')),